# VBA Error 1004 PivotTables

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I have been working in excel creating macros to more easily create graphs as my data changes. Recently many of my macros having been giving me the "Run-time error 1004: Unable to get the PivotTables property of the worksheet class" message. Here is the code:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Value").PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotCache. _
    CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Value!R1:R1048576", TableName:= _
    "PivotTable1", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14
```

Answer (score 0):

Name of the Pivot table is mismatching - see below 2 lines of your code. Line 1 contains "PivotTable2" and table name is "PivotTable1"

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Value").PivotTables("PivotTable2").
      TableName:= "PivotTable1"
```

Comment: I have tried changing them both to PivotTable1 and it still gives the same error message and I have tried changing them both to PivotTable2 and still the same error.